# $f(x)= \tan x; f^n(0)-{n\choose 2}f^{n-2}(0)+ {n\choose 4}f^{n-4}(0)+...=\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, binomial-coefficients

How should I go about proving following relation $f(x)=\tan(x)$, then
$$f^n(0)-{n\choose 2}f^{n-2}(0)+ {n\choose 4}f^{n-4}(0)+...=\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}$$

I tried Maclaurin expansion but not able to get any recursive relation for the expression of $f^n(x)$. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

$$\sin x=f(x)\cos x$$

Use [General Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule)  and [Is the $n^{th}$ derivative of $\sin(x)$ just a translation of $\sin(x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2300972/is-the-nth-derivative-of-sinx-just-a-translation-of-sinx)